# How Upload image in Sylius

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I just downloaded and installed fine the Sylius symfony proyect.

But when I try to upload one image file :

in /admin => Products => (after selecting one) Edit product => Media => Choose file

... I can see the image in the admin score, but when I click 'save changes' button the image doesn't appear anywhere, not in frontend and not in backend (just I see it in one folder in my proyect directory: public/media/image/87/2c).

Perhaps the problem is in liipimaginebundle's config file: there is a /media/cache directory in it that doesn't exits.

Anyone who has downloaded Sylius recently had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

So you see the file in the `media/image` folder, which is good. If you go again into Media for that product, do you see the item listed there? To be shown on the frontend you need to give a type, e.g. `main` to know which one is the main image.

Are you able to replicate this issue on https://demo.sylius.org/admin? If so, I think you are hitting a bug which you can report on the GitHub repository. If not, I feel it might be related to your development and/or hosting set-up. I think it's good to rule it out on the demo admin first. I can't get it replicated on the demo it seems.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. To your first question: when I give it to Media, the image is no longer visible. I've tried several types: main, thumbnail. But the image is not loaded in the application.

I have continued to investigate and it seems that the problem comes from the configuration of the Liipimaginebundle bundle for Symfony, which is not adapted for Symfony 4. I have not yet found anyone who works for it in any forum.

To your second question: when I open https://demo.sylius.org/admin I get the following error: "SORRY This page does not exist yet."

Comment: Ok. Then it sounds like a bug to me. Maybe you can be helped on Slack, or if you have information on how to reproduce it, please file an issue on GitHub. I've notified the Sylius owners about the demo not working.